# Back4App Push Notifications with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, parse-platform, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I've been searching a while now for a full sample of how to add Push Notifications to Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS and all i've gotten is pieces of information that really don't connect . In the Parse Documentation there is a Step by Step sample for Android but its not clear whether you add firebase to the project or not . If somebody has a sample for Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS using FCM and Parse (doesn't matter which BaaS) that would save all of the Xamarin Community a lot of time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to this [Xamarin official sample for FCM](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/Firebase/FCMNotifications) on github.